# Least Destructive Way to Reduce an Image in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize

I do a lot of macro photography and shoot RAW files. I'll edit the RAW files how i see fit, then duplicate them to a template I use that's @72dpi and 996x600 (this is how my website handles the images). To resize the image I use the transform option and hold shift.  I save them by using the "save for Web feature" as png-24.

I notice what feels like a large loss of quality from the RAW to the PNG. Just at 100% magnification.

Any suggestions as to how to preserve the image best when reducing the resolution would be much appreciated!

Comment: I would have thought (correct me if I'm wrong) that, despite the fact that you *can* compress PNGs, they are still a lossless format, therefore there should be no loss of quality; practically a 1:1 duplication of the pixels used in the RAW? Have you tried zooming in to a particular area of the raw, take a simple screen shot into something like PaintBrush (yep - I know!), then convert, repeat and compare the screen shot image pixels?

Comment: Also, what colour profiling (if any) are you using?  Does colour profiling in Photoshop affect RAW images like it does with something like PNGs?

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of your Save for Web settings by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

In Photoshop go to `Image>Image Size(Alt+Ctrl+I)`.

Type in the Pixel size you want and Choose `Bicubic Sharper(reduction)` under the `Resample Option`(Make sure the check is ticked).

Press OK.

[image: Image Size Dialog]

After that goto `File>Save as` and choose `PNG(*.PNG;*.PNS)` under the `Save as type:` Option(There is no need to use the Save for Web Option. IN CC2017 its marked as Legacy)

[image: Save as Dialog]

Also keep in mind that your RAW Image might have a resolution of 4000px+ and 996x600 is very small(Too small for Modern Screens to be honest.). Maybe use a resolution like 1280x720.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I tried this, however I see no difference in quality.

Comment: Yeah...the resolution you use is too low...there is no other way except increasing the Resolution to HD or even FHD. Most Modern screens have Full HD (my smartphone actually has a 2k display) so just use HD(1280x771) or FHD(1920x1156) (those are the ratios that match the resolution you specified).

Comment: "Resolution too low" is like saying a piece of string is too short. 996x600@72ppi is the correct resolution if it's being displayed at 996x600@72ppi.

Answer (score 1):

I would convert the layer to a **Smart Object** and *then* resize. By using a smart object, you tell Photoshop to reference the *original* pixel data upon output. That means the original size/ppi of the image prior to the reduction.

Any quality loss as a result of saving as a PNG would then be due to PNG settings specifically and not the reduction directly.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't resize the originals at all.

Work at full resolution, as your current method, but then just do the resize at the point you Save for Web. [I would still use the legacy Web save for this, not the new version, as it preserves your exif data]

Set to PNG-24, no transparency unless it actually exists in your original image.
Check Convert to sRGB
Size to 996 x 600
Bicubic Sharper
[This is essentially the same as SitiSchu said, but in a single step]
Hit Save...

[image]

You will lose detail - that's inevitable as you are stepping down to potentially 16% of your original size, but you don't have to undo the sizing of your original, or forget & overwrite it with the smaller version.